# When resuming from suspend, dekstop icons glitch out. (nvidia problem?)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, icons, kde

When resuming after a suspend my desktop icons glitch out like shown here;

https://imgur.com/a/GrKjbth

This does not happen consistenly however; it happens randomly.

specs;
(NEOFETCH)

ccpeters@ccpeters-Lenovo-ideapad-510-15ISK

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: 80SR Lenovo ideapad 510-15ISK 
Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic 
Uptime: 17 mins 
Packages: 2465 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX 
GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics 
Memory: 857MiB / 7882MiB

I'm using kde plasma 5.12 on kubuntu 18.04 LTS, with the nvidia-390 drivers.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372710/kde5-after-resume-from-suspend-i-have-corrupted-labels-under-icons

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the Nvidia driver. You need to restart plasmashell. You can accomplish this with either of these scripts which will run automatically if these instructions are followed.

---

**Method 1: handled by system**

Create a file named *suspend_resume.sh* located in */lib/systemd/system-sleep/*

```
#!/bin/bash
# this fixes issue where desktop icon text is removed after resume using nvidia graphics driver

# suspend section
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
# put suspend commands here

# resume section
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
# restart plasmashell
killall plasmashell && kstart plasmashell &
fi
```

After creating the script you will need to make it executable by running this command.

```
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/suspend_resume.sh
```

See this link for more information on the bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1634389

---

**Method 2: handled by desktop**

Create a file named *graphics_reset.sh* in *~/bin/kubuntu/* (or whatever you like, adjust remaining code as required)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Reset plasmashell after graphics glitch (usually after resume)

#resets plasmashell
kquitapp5 plasmashell && plasmashell &
```

After creating the script you will need to make it executable by running this command.

```
chmod +x ~/bin/kubuntu/graphics_reset.sh
```

- Go to system settings > Notifications
- Change "event source:" to KWin Window Manager
- Select "Graphics Reset"
- Check the "Run command" option and browse to the file you created
- Click apply

---

Note: For my setup running these scripts automatically caused an issue where the volume widget would not show any devices and I could not change the volume; however the sound did actually work. There would be a red dash next to the speaker icon. I suppose the script commands are running before the sound drivers are re-established. Adding sleep commands to the script did not solve this either.

Running the script from method 2 manually after resume works and does not cause any issue with the volume widget. There may be alternative volume control widgets that would not have this issue.